# if $x,y,z\ge0$ Prove $x^3+y^3+z^3+3xyz\ge xy(x+y)+yz(y+z)+zx(z+x)$

Tags: inequality

> if $x,y,z\ge0$ Prove $$x^3+y^3+z^3+3xyz\ge xy(x+y)+yz(y+z)+zx(z+x)$$

*Things I have done:* At first i thought this can be solved by AM-GM but I was wrong. I tried to move $RHS$ to $LHS$ and result was $$x(x-y)(x-z)+y(y-z)(y-x)+z(z-x)(z-y)\ge 0$$

then i tired WLOG $x\ge y \ge z$ thus $$x(x-y)(x-z)\ge0,z(z-x)(z-y)\ge 0$$ but $y(y-z)(y-x)\le0$. so possibilities are that $x\ge y \ge z$ did not used properly by me or $LHS-RHS\ge0$ is not good idea at all. any hint or solutions is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: My first reaction is that the equivalent form $$x(x-y)(x-z)+z(x-z)(y-z)\geq y(x-y)(y-z)$$ seems like the better one to assess under the condition $x\geq y\geq z\geq 0$, since the terms on the LHS and RHS are explicitly positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obtain the equivalent form

$$x(x-y)(x-z)+y(y-z)(y-x)+z(z-x)(z-y)\ge 0.$$

This is a standard fact known as [Schur's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur's_inequality). It has a simple proof, which is given in the link.

Comment: thanks.wiki link was very good.I have question from it.would you please explain what _similarly sorted_ means?I go to the URL about it in the wiki page but I did not understand it.

Comment: @user2838619 For example, if the smallest element of $(a,b,c)$ is the 3rd element $c$, then the smallest element of $(x,y,z)$ should be the 3rd element $z$. If $a$ is the largest element, then $x$ should be also. The corresponding elements of the triples should be in corresponding places in the ordering.

Answer (score 1):

I have $4$ SOS form!

1. (Is mine) $$\sum a(a-b)(a-c) = \frac{3abc \sum (a-b)^2 + (a+b+c) \sum (a+b-c)^2 (a-b)^2}{2(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca)} \geqq 0$$
2. By xzlbq(AoPS) and HaiDangel: $$\sum x(x-y)(x-z)=\frac{(x-y)^2xy}{y+z}+\frac{(x-z)^2xz}{y+z}+\frac{(y-z)^2(x-y-z)^2}{y+z}$$
3. (xzlbq - AoPS)
   $$\frac{z}{x+y}[x(x-z)^2+y(y-z)^2]+[(x+y-z)^2x+(x+y-z)^2z]\frac{(x-y)^2}{(x+y)(z+x)}$$
   $$ = y(y-z)(y-x)+z(z-x)(z-y)+x(x-y)(x-z)$$
4. By Edward_Tur (AoPS):
   $$\sum a(a-b)(a-c).\left(\sum a^2 -\sum ab\right)=\sum a(a-b)^2 (a-c)^2 \geqq 0.$$
   $\textbf{Edit.}$ The second SOS was getted from our (I and Haidangel)'s idea for *SOSmethod*:
   If we have $$\it{Sum}= \it{AB}+ \it{C}= -\it{AD}+ \it{E}\to\it{Sum}= \frac{\it{D}\it{C}+ \it{B}\it{E}}{\it{D}+ \it{B}},$$
   where $B,D,C,E$ are postive polynomials.